# Why does multiprocessing.Queue.put() seem faster at pickling a numpy array than actual pickle?

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

It appears that I can call `q.put` 1000 times in under 2.5ms. How is that possible when just pickling that very same array 1000 times takes over 2 seconds?

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(1024,1024)
>>> q = Queue()
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: q.put(a), number=1000)
0.0025581769878044724
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: pickle.dumps(a), number=1000)
2.690145633998327
```

Obviously, I am not understanding something about how `Queue.put` works. Can anyone enlighten me?

I also observed the following:

```
>>> def f():
...   q.put(a)
...   q.get()
```

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: f(), number=1000)
42.33058542700019
```

This appears to be more realistic and suggests to me that simply calling `q.put()` will return before the object is actually serialized. Is that correct?

Comment: where this queue came from?

Comment: given what I understand of multiprocesing, the pickling is done when needing to transfer things between processes, in your example you're not doing so, so there isn't any need to pickle anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` implementation has a number of moving parts under the covers. Here, dealing with a `multiprocessing.Queue` is mostly done in a hidden (to the end user) worker thread. `.put()` just puts an object pointer on a queue (fast and constant-time), and that worker thread does the actual pickling, when it gets around to it.

This *can* burn you, though:  if, in your example, the main program goes on to mutate the `np` array, after the `.put()`, an undefined number of those mutations may be captured by the eventually pickled state. The user-level `.put()` only captures the object pointer, nothing about the object's state.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. This is what it looked like and as shown by the time it takes to eventually `.get`